# how to make derived class to define data structure

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am writing a program to solve puzzles

Every type of puzzle inherits from Puzzle class(virtual).

like this

class Jump_peg::Puzzle

puzzle solver(written using templates) tries every next step of puzzle and next of those who 
tried till it get answers.

But every puzzle has different data structure for 'step'

How I can use 'state' in puzzle(virtual class) so that all its derived class would define there separate 'step' data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a state class that has the interfaces the base puzzle class needs.  For example say that you need  to be able to copy states

```
class state {
  public:
  virtual state *copy() = 0;
  virtual ~state();
};
```

Then create an abstract method to construct states in the puzzle class

```
class puzzle {
virtual state *initial_state(void) = 0;
  virtual step(void) = 0;
```

};

And in your specific puzzle class for a specific type of puzzle, define a new state class for that type of puzzle, and create methods that will return that type of state and can be called from the base class.  You probably also need iterators to know what the possible next steps are and to know how good/close to a solution you are.

Comment: "abstract method" -- Did you mean *pure virtual member function*?

Comment: @jefffrey Yes; pure virtual member function is perhaps a bit more clear, although I think abstract is sufficiently common in generic object-oriented terminology that it's reasonable to use when talking about C++.  But the point is more to define the interface between the state and puzzle class in a state class which probably will not be useful to directly instantiate and likely has pure virtual member functions.